# Loop for checking elements in XML (JS/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have created script that puts data into table, then I get this data and save as XML. This is my XML structure.

```
<countries>
    <country>
        <iso>af</iso>
        <visitors>0</visitors>
    </country>
    <country>
        <iso>ax</iso>
        <visitors>0</visitors>
    </country>
    <country>
        <iso>al</iso>
        <visitors>0</visitors>
    </country>
</countries>
```

and now, I would like to create a loop, which will go through all countries, and if for example iso=us, then change color of us class to black, the last part of changing color is the simplest haha but generally I don't know how to start, because I wonder is my XML structure good for this task? Loop should go through all countries, check their iso, and then change their color, depends on what value is in  if visitors<50 change to grey, visitors>50 change to black for example. I have to user loop, because we have 249 countries with ISO standard.

Comment: Please add code what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('countries').find('country').each(function() {
    var iso = $.trim( $('iso', this).text() );

    if ( iso == 'us' ) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, just find the `country` elements, get the text of the child `iso` element, and compare it against something ?

Comment: You could do `$('iso:contains(us)').closest('country')` but jQuery still has to loop through all iso elements to match that selector, so it's probably not any more efficient.